# Dynamically setting delivery_method_options in a before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

The [Action Mailer Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks) guide states:

> You could use a before_action to populate the mail object with defaults, `delivery_method_options` or insert default headers and attachments.

However, I don't see how it could be possible to set `delivery_method_options` by doing this, as this value is only fetched from the `headers` argument explicitly passed to the `mail` method. Am I missing something, or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: I think you are right, I might try to submit a patch if I have some time!

Answer (score 0):

The [Action Mailer Basics guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) was, in fact, misleading. I submitted [a PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40709) to fix the guide.

In order to define "per-mailer" delivery options, you need to use an `after_action` callback:

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer 
  after_action :set_delivery_options
 
  private
 
    def set_delivery_options
      # You have access to the mail instance,
      # @business and @user instance variables here
      if @business && @business.has_smtp_settings?
        mail.delivery_method.settings.merge!(@business.smtp_settings)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been working around it by redefining the `apply_defaults` method in the mailer. I tried the `after_action` approach, but in my mailer specs, though it sets the delivery options for the mail, it somehow caused an issue with the other attributes of the object (i.e., the subject becomes "Test" instead of what I set it to). This could be a test environment specific bug. Were you able to confirm the `after_action` approach sends mails properly.